# Issue in create trigger phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have a problem creating a trigger in phpmyadmin. Here is my syntax:

```
DECLARE n_ubicacion VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT '';

IF (OLD.id_ubicacion <> NEW.id_ubicacion) THEN 
SELECT ubicacion INTO n_ubicacion FROM ubicacions WHERE id = NEW.id_ubicacion LIMIT 1;
END IF;

INSERT INTO historico_equipos(usuario, id_equipo, estado, ubicacion, empleado, f_asignacion, created_at) VALUES (CURRENT_USER(), NEW.id, NEW.id_estado, n_ubicacion, NEW.id_empleado, NEW.f_asignacion, CURRENT_DATE())
```

I don''t know where is the problem. In phpmyadmin show the next error:

Something is wrong in your syntax near 'DECLARE n_ubicacion VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT ''; IF (OLD.id_ubicacion <> NEW.id_ubicacion) THEN'

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if any other statements are present inside the Trigger above the DECLARE statement. If so, then it may throw the error.
2. Check your delimiter. By default, MySQL's delimiter is ';'. So, on seeing the first ';', your query will break. Hence use some other delimiter before creating the trigger.

**Example:**

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER ...
BEGIN
DECLARE n_ubicacion VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT '';
IF (OLD.id_ubicacion <> NEW.id_ubicacion) THEN 
    SELECT ubicacion INTO n_ubicacion FROM ubicacions WHERE id =
                                       NEW.id_ubicacion LIMIT 1;
END IF;
INSERT INTO historico_equipos(usuario, id_equipo, estado, ubicacion, empleado, f_asignacion, created_at) VALUES (CURRENT_USER(), NEW.id, NEW.id_estado, n_ubicacion, NEW.id_empleado, NEW.f_asignacion, CURRENT_DATE())
END//
```

Then again change the DELIMITER to default.

`DELIMITER ;`

Comment: I'm configuring it in the definition field of phpmyadmin triggers. I've added the `DELIMITER //` and `DELIMITER ;` at the end of my syntax, but it shows the same error.